# Drawbacks to using rubygems s3 source?

Tags: rubygems, bundler

When using the following versions, installing new gems was *painfully* slow.

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p0 (2013-02-24 revision 39474) [x86_64-darwin12.3.0]

$ gem -v
2.0.3

$ bundle -v
Bundler version 1.3.5
```

I've noticed a rather incredible speedup accessing the api can be had by pointing bundler directly at the s3 store thereby avoiding the 302 redirects:

1. with first line of `Gemfile` set to `source 'https://rubygems.org'`

   ```
   $ time bundle update
   bundle update  5.16s user 0.21s system 2% cpu 3:19.20 total
   ```
2. using `source 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/production.s3.rubygems.org'`

   ```
   $ time bundle update
   bundle update  22.70s user 0.44s system 37% cpu 1:01.68 total
   ```

Numbers above from a freshly generated rails 4 app's bundle on a mid-2008 macbook pro. The observed difference is more marked when actually installing gems than when only updating the lock file.

What drawbacks are there to the s3 source?

As it is consistently *minutes* faster, is there any serious reason not to use it?

Comment: The issue here is exacerbated by the lack of ipv6 AAAA records for rubygems.org combined with an ISP-enforced Alcatel Lucent "Cellpipe" 7130 rental modem which announces itself as the DNS server over DHCP but which times out on AAAA queries (but not on anything else)!